# How can linux kthread be terminated from two different places?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

In my driver's probe function, I am creating and running kernel thread using `kthread_run`.

In my thread function I am using `kthread_should_stop()`.  Two scenarios here,

1. Check one condition and if condition is satisfied, threads go on running until `kthread_stop` terminates it.
2. If that condition is not satisfied, get out of `kthread_should_stop()` because I do not want to continue my functionality(e.g. polling) resulting thread gets terminated.

In driver's remove function, I am using `kthread_stop` to terminate the thread. Now, if I remove my driver module with **rmmod** or **modprobe**, I get kernel panic in case of second scenario which may be because of thread is no longer alive and `kthread_stop` attempts to terminate it.

> Is there a way to fix this?

Sample code for more clarity(please note it is minimal code to understand the problem).

```
static int probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
      thread = kthread_run(poll_task, power, "poll_task");
}

static int remove(struct i2c_client *client)
{
      kthread_stop(thread)      
}
static int poll_task(void *data)
{
    while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        if (condition)
            goto exit;
            .
            .
            .
    }  
exit:
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a work job rather than thread.

Comment: You could probably replace `kthread_run()` with a sequence of `kthread_create()`, `get_tasK_struct()`, and `wake_up_process()`. This will keep a reference to the thread's `struct task_struct`. Then, to kill the thread, call `kthread_stop()` followed by `put_task_struct()`.